# Regex: change the order of the controls

Tags: regex

I would like to check if a string contains:

- at least 1 number
- at least 2 characters (uppercase or lowercase)

This is the regex I though I might use:

```
(?=(?:.*?\d))(?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){2})
```

With aa1 the test gives a false statement, while with a1a or 1aa it gives a true result.

The strange thing is that if I change the order of the controls in the regexp:

```
(?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:.*?\d))
```

all 3 of the test string I used wives a true value.

How is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: 1. What language/engine is this happening on? I just tried in Python and both of those produce identical results. 2. There's no need for all those extra parentheses! They just make the regex harder to follow.

Comment: NOTE: The reason for the rollback of Gumbo's edit is that it may affect the appearance of the bug being investigated.

Comment: @Max: The regexes need to be formatted; otherwise SO eats some of the characters and turns them to garbage.  Also, take a closer look at the regexes: all the parentheses are in fact necessary.

Comment: @Alan: The parantheses around `.*?\d` are not necessary. My bad about the formatting though; the history view is deceiving in its change highlighting (no initial space highlighting).

Comment: @Max: Okay, those parens can go, but that hardly counts as parenthesis abuse around here! ;)  As for the edit history, I don't think it used to highlight anything when someone just indented for code formatting; maybe that's what threw you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't happen to be writing this in JavaScript and testing in Internet Explorer, would you?  That configuration has a [known bug](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug) that causes this kind of error.

Comment: You're right: I've tested regex with IE7. I found the recommended article very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not strange. Your first regex checks if there is one number **followed** somewhere by 2 chars.
The second one checks it in the other way. You need to take both cases in account.

Something like this should work (not tested)

```
/(\d(?:.*?)[a-z]{2})|([a-z]{2}(?:.*?)\d)/i
```

Comment: Those are lookaheads. They do not consume characters and therefore match at the same position. Switching two consecutive lookaheads around should make no difference in the result (though may affect performance quite a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])
```

Or a little more compact:

```
(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})
```